Можно ли сделать разные цвета текста в связке ConEmu и Clink?
В разделе ConEmu - "Цвета", 8. цвет стоит белый.

На скрине я набрал "ssh", дальше подсказка из истории Clink (новая версия) и всё одним цветом.
Это можно исправить? Чтобы ввод был одним цветом, а подсказка другим.
